# Simple Rails Blog - Post Comments are ignoring Post ID [outside comment array in parameters]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-activerecord

I have a simple blog I'm building with Rails, and I'm following the normal rails getting started guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).  I'm setting up a form for comments inside my post's show method, but when I save, it's not saving the page_id in the comment record.

```
= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], :remote => true do |f|

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :extra_field, @page.rsvp_extra_field
    = f.text_area :extra_field
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessible :comments_attributes, :comment_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :extra_field, :name, :post_id, :phone

end
```

I see in the rails console that it's posting it, but putting `NULL` for post_id.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I didn't change my create method at all:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**EDIT 2**

I think my parameters are nested when I don't want them to be... any ideas how to get this "post_id" inside of the "comment" array?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eqe6C7/ND35TDwtJ95w0fJVk4PSvznCR01T4OzuA49g=",
"comment"=>{"name"=>"test", "extra_field"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "post_id"=>"8"}
```

Comment: What does the controller look like receiving the create call?

Comment: Added it above. I didn't change it from the default.  I thought it had something to do with vanity urls, so I refactored them and now the JS is passing post_id as an argument, but the insert SQL has NULL for post_id... ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your method `create` in `CommentsController`, create object `Comment` unrelated to the object `Post`. `has_many` relation provide 3 methods for related objects:

```
post.comments.create
post.comments.create!
post.comments.build(eq new method)
```

Add in your `CommentsController` this:

```
  ...
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  end
  ...
```